# Query by Category and Custom Field - Shortcode

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, shortcode

I have been working on a shortcode to Query by a Specific Category and display all posts in the category if the specified custom field is populated.  What I have created to this point was started with code I found and I made changes to fit my needs.

I have updated the code using the $query .= '&meta_key='.$custom_field; and that took care of the main problem.

I am not able to get the pagination to work.

Any ideas?

I was looking at other options instead of using "extract" but I can't seem to get any other array to work.

```
function custom_query_category($atts, $content = null) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "pagination" => 'true',
        "query" => '',
        "category" => '',
        "custom_field" => '',
    ), $atts));

    global $wp_query,$paged,$post;
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();

    if($pagination == 'true'){
        $query .= '&paged='.$paged;
    }   
    if(!empty($category)){
        $query .= '&category_name='.$category;
    }   
    if(!empty($custom_field)){
        $query .= '&meta_key='.$custom_field;
    }
    if(!empty($query)){
        $query .= $query;
    }

    $wp_query->query($query);

    ob_start();

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    if ( strlen(get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true)) > 0 ) {  //Used to check the Custom Field to see if it is populated
    ?>

    <div style="margin:10px 0 30px;"></div>         
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <h3 style="margin:0 0 10px 0;"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>
        <div class="one-third-width-responsive">
        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );  ?>
        </div>
        <div class="two-third-width-responsive">
        </a>        
        <div style="font-size:15px;"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true); ?></div>  //Displays Custom Field Value
        </div>
        <?php } else {} ?>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <div style="margin-top:35px;"></div>

    <?php if(pagination == 'true'){ ?>
    <div class="navigation" style="margin:20px 0 35px 0;">
      <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('« Previous') ?></div>
      <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More »') ?></div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

        <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}

add_shortcode("custom_query_category", "custom_query_category");

?>
```

Comment: please double-check that `field_name` is a valid query parameter; https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Avoid using `extract`, it confuses editors and tools and can pollute the local namespace in weird and unexpected ways, as well as encourage errors that are difficult to debug. Also there's no query var called `field_name`. Also post meta queries ( custom fields ) are super slow, never try to query for posts by their post meta, use a taxonomy instead

Comment: Can you give me an example of the proper way to change from using extract ?

Comment: The "&field_name" was the problem.  I changed it to:

$query .= '&meta_key='.$custom_field;

and it works perfectly.  I am still concerned about using extract though.